# incoming email with domain.com to resolve to amazon ec2 email format

Tags: amazon-ec2, godaddy

I need to a way for an incoming email such as example@domain.com to resolve to example@ec2-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com since we are using amazon ec2.

Our DNS is on godaddy - can anyone help me with the syntax. I tried setting up a CNAME record but it doesn't work since I have an A record that resolves the domain to an IP.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Say what? What exactly are you doing? Are you trying to host your domain's email service on EC2?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't how email delivery works.

If you truly need email sent to `user@domain.com` to land on that EC2 instance, then you need to set an MX record for `domain.com` that points to `ec2-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com`, then configure your MTA on that EC2 instance to handle emails to `domain.com`. If you just need email to eventually get to that box, I'd host email elsewhere and then poll that remote mailbox from the EC2 instance using fetchmail, getmail, or the like.

Caveat: for receiving mail, this should work fine. If you're going to be sending mail from this host, you're going to run into a bunch of problems, as many major mail providers have blacklisted all of the EC2 netblocks. For outbound, I'd recommend using Amazon's SES service or another third-party mail relay.